# Laravel Websockets problem integrating with Laradock

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I can set up the package [LaravelWebsockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) and I have it up and running with [Laradock](https://laradock.io/). But I'm having troubles trying to use the Event Creator. When I try to create a new one it says: "Error sending event" and the POST response is an error 500 (server code error).

The full response is:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastException",
    "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php",
    "line": 119,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Dashboard/Http/Controllers/SendMessage.php",
            "line": 26,
            "function": "broadcast",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 48,
            "function": "__invoke",
            "class": "BeyondCode\\LaravelWebSockets\\Dashboard\\Http\\Controllers\\SendMessage",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 219,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 680,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/src/Dashboard/Http/Middleware/Authorize.php",
            "line": 11,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "BeyondCode\\LaravelWebSockets\\Dashboard\\Http\\Middleware\\Authorize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 41,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
            "line": 75,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 66,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 682,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 657,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 623,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/app/Http/Middleware/CorsMiddleware.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\CorsMiddleware",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the problem is only using Laradock because if I run outside from the container with `php composer serve` it works fine and the Event Creator presents no problem.

It should response "ok" but as I said I get 500 error code with this API call: `http://localhost/laravel-websockets/event`

Comment: iam not 100% sure whats the problem but https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo might help

Comment: Thanks, I followed this series as a reference but I'm using [Laravel Websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) with is entirely built in PHP difference from the [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)

Comment: he is using pusher which you are using too :D i use laravel websockets too it can use the pusher php broad caster library but not the 3rd party api so same function names same every thing also not all hosts support php websockets